# PyQt4 x64 is not importing from network location

Tags: python, network-programming, pyqt

I want to use PyQt4 from a network location.

I installed Python 2.6.4 x32 in a client and kept PyQt4 x32 module in a network share (for Ex: "\share\Pyton_Modules\x32").

when opened python i did as below and it worked

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'\\share\Pyton_Modules\x32')

from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

everything worked fine.
But i tested the same way for python 2.6.4 x64 in a client and keeping PyQt4 x64 in a network share (for Ex : "\share\Pyton_Modules\x64")

when opened python i did as below and it didn't worked

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'\\share\Pyton_Modules\x64')

from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

i get below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: could it be a typo in `Pyton_Modules`?

Comment: I have installed pyhon and PyQt4 x64 in a local mechine and tested it worked, then i moved `PyQt4` folder and `sip.pyd` from "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages" to "\\share\Pyton_Modules\x64". i used the same command on other mechine where only Python x64 is installed and acessing PyQt4 from network location. So there is no chance of any typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to overcome my situation.

I moved all the files from `PyQt4\bin` to `PyQt4` and it worked without any issue...

Hope this could help someone.